# Need help understanding error in algorithm converting BST to sorted array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Array used to make the BST (that my function takes as an input): `[38,95,70,5,10,148,93]`

As of now the the function only returns `[5,10]`, instead of returning all elements in a sorted order. What is wrong with this approach?

```js
function sortedArrayFromBST(tree,node,outputArray){
    outputArray=outputArray||[]
    // console.log(tree)
    node=node||tree.root
    console.log(node)
    let left=node.left
    console.log(left)
    let right=node.right
    console.log(right)
    if(left ==null){
        outputArray.push(node.data)
    }else{
        return sortedArrayFromBST(tree,left,  outputArray) 
    }
    
    if(right==null){
        return outputArray
    } else{
        return sortedArrayFromBST(tree, right, outputArray)
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the heart of your recursive function you want to do something like the following:

```js
if (node === null) // base case
    return
if (node.left !== null)
    sortedArrayFromBST(node.left, outputArray)
outputArray.push(node.val)
if (node.right !== null)
    sortedArrayFromBST(node.right, outputArray)

return outputArray
```

Your conditions right now are not correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. I still have a hard time understanding recursion in these types of functions. For the simpler stuff I can get them working pretty easily but I struggle a lot here!

Answer (score 2):

The `return` conditions you're using are wrong. Instead of returning from the `left` node, you need to append it's values to the output and then process the `right` node.

```js
function sortedArrayFromBST(tree, node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return []
    }
    outputArray = []

    let left = node.left
    let right = node.right

    outputArray.push(sortedArrayFromBST(tree, left))
    outputArray.push(node.data)
    outputArray.push(sortedArrayFromBST(tree, right))
    return outputArray
}
```